# how to extract height and width from a svg file

Tags: php, svg, height, width

example:

```
<svg width="23" height="22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
<g>
<title>Layer 1</title>
<path fill-opacity="0" id="svg_1" d="m23,2-20,9.5l22,9" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffffff" />
</g>
</svg>
```

I want to extract the width and height of the svg file so that I can do some positioning with canvg.

I know it's xml, but I can't figure it out.  It's probably something really easy but it's the last day of the year and I can't figure it out.

Been trying:

PHP SimpleXML

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($imageright) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml->getDocNamespaces());echo '</br>';
```

giving me 
    Array ( [] => http://www.w3.org/2000/svg )

This also doesn't work:

```
foreach($xml->svg[0]->attributes() as $a => $b)
  {
  echo $a,'="',$b,"\"</br>";
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($imageright);
$attr = $xml->attributes();
printf("%s x %s", $attr->width, $attr->height);
```

Output

```
23 x 22
```

[Simple Online Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TAkwJ2)

Comment: `simplexml_load_file()` will load the entire SVG into memory - Loading even 1K to read two numbers early in the file doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @NateSymer I want to believe that is just an example.