# PHP How to determine height and width of SVG Image ONLY by its path co-ordinates?

Tags: php, svg

I have a few hundred SVG files. Which do not have any height or width values.

I would like to know if its possible to work out the height and width of the SVG image by only using its path co-ordinates.

How would would this look in PHP. I thought imagemagick would be able to but it can not.

If anyone knows how I can achieve this it would be a great help and save me endless hours..

Thanks

Comment: SVG files don't have height and width values (kind of the point of an SVG, infinitely scalable), they do however they do have a height to width ratio see here http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

Comment: Yes, i am aware of this. But path co-ordinates make up an image that if put on a canvas will have an initial height and width. This is what I want to find out.

Comment: I understand, but it not stored like that, it will know that it is x pixels (for example) from its boundary, but this boundary (canvas) can have any size, it like asking "I want to know the size of a carpet, but this carpet can go in any size room but always be 1cm from the edge". so height and width are always relitive to the container, hope that helps

Comment: When an svg image is resized in an svg editor eg. adobe illustrator, the path co-ordinates change without the need to have height and width values. So what you are saying doesn't make sense. There is definately a way to do this.

Comment: That is correct the vector (paths or strokes) change because all the points (nodes) are relative to an x,y coordinate emanating from the centre.  With that in mind an SVG is just an XML file contained within that you may find height and width coordinates but these will be of the container. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532261/php-how-to-get-width-and-height-of-a-svg-picture and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105684/how-to-extract-height-and-width-from-a-svg-file.  Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Pwner, this is what I mean. I need the container height and width.. But my files only have the path co-ordinates.. that's all. Im really baffled, I've looked everywhere for a solution, no one seems to have the advance maths skills :P

Comment: You really can't do this easily with PHP.  Even if you parsed all the coordinates in the path data attribute to find the max and min, it's still possible that the *curves* of the path would extend beyond that.  That said, once you're in the browser, it's easy to find the extent of the path with `.getBBox()`.  Any chance a Javascript-based solution would work for your needs?